# How to get the string of a dynamically modified SVG element of an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, svg

I wrote javascript which dynamically edits an svg element. I want to get the new string of the edited svg element but currently my code fails.
I found here the following code to get the string form of an HTML document.

```
var txt = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

I just want the `innerHTML` of the SVG element.  I tried the following code but get an error message saying "undefined".

```
var svgnode=document.getElementById("svgnode1");
alert(svgnode.innerHTML);
```

How do I do that.  The error occurs on Google Chrome but I want a solution that works on any browser.

Comment: Can you post more of your Code? Is the id of the svg-element the mentioned "svgnode1"?

Comment: When you say "I found here ...", did you mean to link to something?

Comment: Sorry. I found the code in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`innerHTML` is defined for HTML documents but not for XML DOMs of other kinds.

There is some mechanism planned for `innerHTML` like facilities for SVG.  http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/SVG_2_DOM#innerHTML_type_facilities:

> **innerHTML type facilities**
>
> It would be good if XML had an `innerHTML`-like feature. Writing markup in an ECMAScript string can be a bit of a pain, but it can also simplify things a lot, and to get better that that for the types of scenario in which it's useful probably means E4X-like capabilities.
>
> Calling this facility `innerHTML` would make it seem like the markup should be parsed as being in the XHTML namespace, so maybe `innerMarkup` or `insertCode` would be a better name, or, for symmetry with `textContent`, maybe `markupContent`.

If what you need is a way to turn SVG, or any other XML DOM into a string of XML, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

> - [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) to serialize DOM trees to strings

or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916895/20394 for the IE equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Some actual code (Tested in Google-Chrome and IE 11):

```
<object id="sv" data="Switzerland_regions.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <!-- <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />-->
</object>


<script type="text/javascript">
        var S = document.getElementById("svgnode1")

        var markup = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(S.contentDocument.rootElement);
        console.log(markup);


        // var SD = S.getSVGDocument();

        // var circle1 = SD.getElementById("GR");
        // console.log(circle1);
        // circle1.style.fill = "grey";

         //var rectangle = SD.querySelector("#layer4");
        //var parent = rectangle.parentNode;
        //parent.removeChild(rectangle);
</script>
```