# remove element from svg string

Tags: jquery, string, svg

I have a svg string `str="<svg....</svg>"`:

```
<svg width="612" height="394" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="100" width="77" y="49.25" x="16.75" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <rect id="svg_2" height="127" width="160" y="176.25" x="343.75" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 2</title>
  <rect id="svg_3" height="112" width="174" y="28.25" x="194.75" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <text transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1.07143, 0, -8.80357)" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_4" y="94.85" x="281.75" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">Hello</text>
  <rect id="svg_5" height="92" width="103" y="20.25" x="422.75" stroke-width="2" stroke="#ff9900" fill="#0000ff"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to get other string but without an element. How can I do to remove the text element from the second layer? I have tried `var fstr = $(str).wrapAll('<div>').find('g:eq(1) text:eq(0)').remove().closest('div').html();` but it doesn't work. Any solution? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return back to an SVG string, you need to use the [`XMLSerializer` (or corresponding equivalents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916327/javascript-replacement-for-xmlserializer-serializetostring):

```
var svg = $(str);
svg.children('g:eq(1)').children('text:first').remove();

function serializeXMLNode(xmlNode) {
    if (typeof window.XMLSerializer != "undefined") {
        return (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
    } else if (typeof xmlNode.xml != "undefined") {
        return xmlNode.xml;
    }
    return "";
}

var strUpdated = serializeXMLNode(svg[0]);
console.log(strUpdated);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SbCVr/)