# innerHTML after XMLHttpRequest not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

I have the following black of code which is working perfectly fine on Chrome & Firefox but fails everytime on IE, it returns "undefined" in the console tab.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

test(); 

});


function test()
{

          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/xml/products.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
        console.log(list[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML);

}
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

The XML i'm using is the following :

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: jQuery ajax version not working either:

```
var xmlDoc;     
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/xml/products.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        xmlDoc = xml;
                var list=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
                console.log(list[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML );
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you really need to touch the native XHR? Why don't you use `$.ajax()`, you seem to already have jQuery. It levels a *LOT* of cross-browser quirks, especially with vendor low-level APIs as this!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with ajax , i just wanted to try something else

Comment: You need to check for the state change before you get the response, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576252(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Be assured the problem lies elsewhere. Revert to jQuery and post that code, someone here will be able to help you. Why would `async=false` have something to do with CORS? Am I missing something? Those two aspects are totally unrelated in my book...

Comment: @PatrickEvans ok missed that! But why would you not use async.

Comment: i have updated my question with the ajax code but the result is completely the same ...it works everywhere except IE ( Undefined is returned )

Answer (score 2):

No idea why this works in Chrome and FF, it shouldn't actually<sup>1</sup>.

You are loading an XML document, and are successfully selecting an XML element node. Those don't have `innerHTML` properties<sup>2</sup>. You should use an [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) if you really need to get the markup of your xml document (maybe you're just looking for the `.textContent`?).

```
var el = list[0].childNodes[1];
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(el));
```

However, oldIE doesn't even know that, you'll need to use `el.xml` for them<sup>3</sup>.

<sub>1: At least not in older versions. See also [does innerHTML work with XML Elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6170911/1048572).

2: Apparently, the DOM Parsing spec now includes a generic [`innerHTML` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML) on all DOM elements

3: see [JavaScript: Replacement for XMLSerializer.serializeToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4916327/1048572)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer , in IE i have now XMLSerializer is undefined...:/

Comment: Hm, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975124(v=vs.85).aspx) claims that IE9 has one…